# How do I change the page size for a WkHtmlToXSharp PDF to letter?

Tags: c#, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

How do I change the page size for a WkHtmlToXSharp PDF to letter? By default it outputs 8.26 x 11.69 inches and I need it to be 8.5 x 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://github.com/pruiz/WkHtmlToXSharp/issues/6) and a pull request was submitted but not merged.

Add in a pull request from the GitHub project page: https://github.com/tylerabahr/WkHtmlToXSharp/blob/ad9a935ea01c852133071fabbaf1b7d5a551e517/WkHtmlToXSharp/PdfGlobalSettings.cs

Then write this code:

```
    MultiplexingConverter mc = new MultiplexingConverter();
    mc.GlobalSettings.Dpi = 300;
    mc.GlobalSettings.Size.PageSize = PdfPageSize.Letter;
    PdfMarginSettings pms = new PdfMarginSettings();
    string halfInch = ".5in";
    mc.GlobalSettings.Margin.Bottom = halfInch;
    mc.GlobalSettings.Margin.Left = halfInch;
    mc.GlobalSettings.Margin.Right = halfInch;
    mc.GlobalSettings.Margin.Top = halfInch;
```